# Data not appearing on node - Neo4j

Tags: import, neo4j

I have this csv file

```
Nr_TipoCadeia,Designacao,Descricao
1,Hotel,O hotel � um edif�cio equipado e projectado para albergar as pessoas de forma tempor�ria.
2,Pousada,"As pousadas podem ser uma �tima alternativa aos hot�is, com pre�os mais atrativos e atendimento personalizado."
3,Motel,Motel � um estabelecimento de hospedagem que se diferencia dos demais porque as pessoas geralmente v�o at� ele com o objetivo de manter rela��es sexuais e n�o necess
ariamente para conseguir alojamento.
4,Pensao,"Casa em que se admitem h�spedes, mediante pagamento."
5,Resort," Os resorts possuem servi�os variados de est�tica, quadras poliesportivas e muitas piscinas."
```

I am trying to import the file to Neo4j using the following query:

```
load csv with headers from 'file:///TipoCadeia.csv' as line
create (tipocadeia:TipoCadeia {Nr_TipoCadeia: TOINT(line.Nr_TipoCadeia)})
set tipocadeia.Designacao = line.Designacao,
    tipocadeia.Descricao = line.Descricao
return tipocadeia;
```

Everything is ok, except in the node where the third line of the csv file should be stored, it only appears `<id>:317` when it should be like

```
<id>:317 Nr_TipoCadeia:3 Designacao:Motel Descricao:....
```

The other nodes are fine.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Your query works (I copy/pasted the text from your CSV, 5 nodes with data are created). Check your CSV file for errors or unwanted characters. Troubleshoot with `RETURN line` to not create notes but rather check if the CSV is read correctly.

Comment: I did what you said and the csv file is read correctly, i get the rows with everything in the csv file. But a weird thing happens, the ball itself of the node has this string in it "Motel � um estab". Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: You mean the visualization of the node in the web interface? You can change what is shown as node label.